# IQueryable.Where clause AND not working with multiple search parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search, where-clause, iqueryable

I am having an issue with getting a Multiple search working with a IQueryable.Where Clause using the AND operator.  I know that the problem is when a parameter is blank or null it is searching for a "" with the other parameter and not returning results but I don't want to have to go through an extended and ridiculously nested if to check for nulls or blanks on 8 parameters.  I have googled this for days, the OR works obviously but the AND condition returns nothing.

```
albums = albums.Where(a => a.CA_AlbumName.ToUpper().Contains(searchName.ToUpper()) && 
                           a.CA_AlbumURL.ToUpper().Contains(searchURL.ToUpper()));
```

The above works if both parameters are not blank but returns nothing if one of them is.  I have tried building the where based on not null like below but same results:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchName))
{
    albums = albums.Where(a => a.CA_AlbumName.ToUpper().Contains(searchName.ToUpper()));
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchURL))
{
    albums = albums.Where(a => a.CA_AlbumURL.ToUpper().Contains(searchURL.ToUpper()));
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your requirement right, the following one should work:

```
  albums = albums.Where(a => 
      (
          string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchName) || 
          a.CA_AlbumName.ToUpper().Contains(searchName.ToUpper())
      ) && 
      (
          string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchURL) || 
          a.CA_AlbumURL.ToUpper().Contains(searchURL.ToUpper())
      )
  );
```

@James is right. The updated code is here:

```
  var isSearchNameNullOrEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchName);
  var isSearchURLNullOrEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchURL);    

  albums = albums.Where(a => 
      (
          isSearchNameNullOrEmpty || 
          a.CA_AlbumName.ToUpper().Contains(searchName.ToUpper())
      ) && 
      (
          isSearchURLNullOrEmpty || 
          a.CA_AlbumURL.ToUpper().Contains(searchURL.ToUpper())
      )
  );
```

Comment: +1 I would probably store the results of the string.IsNullOrEmpty() checks somewhere so they're not evaluated each time, but this should work.

Comment: ha!  I just wanted to post that in case somebody decides to cut-and-paste the "magic solution" into their project.  Nice answer and update.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much all...that worked.  It's awesome that you all contribute so quickly, saved my life!

Comment: @user1060406 Be sure to select this as the answer if it worked for you.